# django rest framework post nested json

Tags: json, django-rest-framework

I have a table on sqlserver

```
ext_id is number,
dealer_code is string,
dealer_name is string
```

and I need to POST this json

```
{
    "ext_id": 1,
    "dealer": {
        "dealer_code" : "D1"
        "dealer_name": "Dealer1",
    }
}
```

models.py

```
class reqid(models.Model):
    ext_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    dealer_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="dealer_code")
    dealer_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column="dealer_name")
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table_test'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ext_id
```

serializer.py

```
class ReqSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = reqid
        fields = ['ext_id', 'dealer_code','dealer_name']
```

views.py

```
class testView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = reqid.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReqSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        reqid = request.data.get("reqid")
        dealer_code = request.data['dealer']['dealer_code']
        dealer_name = request.data['dealer']['dealer_name']
        data = {'reqid': reqid, 'dealer_code': dealer_code, 'dealer_name': dealer_name}
        serializer = ReqSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

when I try post json i get

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting ',' delimiter: line 5 column 3 (char 60)"
}
```

if I post simple json like :

```
{
    "ext_id": 1,
    "dealer_code": "D1",
    "dealer_name": "Dealer1"
}
```

everything works. What and where should I change to load nested json.

I am a beginner so please be specific :)

**UPDATE**

Thx @Vishal Singh

Right now I must add more nest "asset"

....

```
"dealer":{
      "dealer_code":"D1",
      "dealer_name":"Dealer1",
   },
   "asset":{
      "sector":{
         "code":"SEC1",
         "name":"Sector1"
      }
   }
```

...

how can I save sector name (I added column to database)?

When I add to views.py

```
sector_name = request.data['asset']['sector']['name']
```

and in serialize.py

```
class SectorField(serializers.Field):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        ret = {
            "sector_name": value.sector_name
        }
        return ret

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ret = {
            "sector_name": data["name"],
        }
        return ret
```

I get

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "sector": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Comment: given JSON is invalid. put a comma after D1 like this `"D1",` and remove the extra comma after `"Dealer1"`.

Comment: A valid json would be ```{"ext_id": 1,"dealer": {"dealer_code" : "D1","dealer_name": "Dealer1"}}```.

Comment: Thx, I change it and right now I get {
    "dealer_code": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "dealer_name": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#using-source

Comment: Thx :) it's working

Comment: @Vishal Singh can you help me with new problem after UPDATE?